# Translations of Luca Pacioli's Summa de arithmetica

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, translations

Are there any English language (or perhaps German, Dutch or French, but preferably English) translations of [Luca Pacioli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luca_Pacioli)'s 1494 (or later edition) "[Summa de arithmetica](http://www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/titleinfo/2683230)"? They do not have to be in print or of recent times, but just anyone in existence.

Beware that there are a lot of translations of only the double-entry bookkeeping part of the *Summa* which do not include the rest of the 600-page work. I can only guess why this is.

Answer (score 3):

If you read French, you will probably have no big difficulty with Latin.
Here is a recent edition:

Summa de arithmetica, geometria, proportioni et proportionalità, hg. Enrico Giusti, Abrizzi, Venedig 1994, ISBN 88-317-6008-4 (Nachdruck der Erstausgabe Paganinis, Venedig 1494).

There is a Russian translation:

Пачоли Л. Трактат о счетах и записях / Под ред. Я. В. Соколова. — М.: Финансы и статистика, 1994.

For another book of Pacioli, English, Italian and Russian translations seem to exist:

Engl. Divine Proportion, Norwalk, CT 2001;

Ital. Übers. Andrea Masini, in: Arnaldo Bruschi u.a. (Hgg.): Scritti rinascimentali di architettura, Mailand 1978, S. 23-244.

Rus. Лука Пачоли. О божественной пропорции. Репринт изд. 1508. С приложением перевода А. И. Щетникова. М.: Фонд «Русский авангард», 2007.

Comment: Thank-you for your answer. The original language of the Summa is not Latin however, but Italian (Tuscan dialect). Interesting that there would be a Russian translation, but no English, German, Dutch or French. Sadly I know no Russian. Beware that there are a lot of translations of only the double-entry bookkeeping part of the Summa which do not include the rest of the 600 page work. I can only guess why this is.

Comment: Soviet Union translated more mathematical books than all European+American countries combined.